# First name hyphenated in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I need to cite an article where one of the author's first name is hyphenated "Shin-Ichi Sasa"
The output I get in my bibliography is as follows

[1] S.-i. Sasa and K. Hayashi, Phys. Rev. E 70, .....

I am using the document class revtex4.1  and bibtex to compile the bibliography from a .bib file

How can I make the output be like?

[1] S-I. Sasa and K. Hayashi, Phys. Rev. E 70, .....

The .bib file has the following entry

```
@Article{HayashiSasa2004,
  author =        {Sasa, Shin-Ichi and Hayashi, Kumiko},
  title =         {Effective temperature in nonequilibrium steady states of Langevin systems with a tilted periodic potential},
  journal =       {Phys. Rev. E},
  year =          {2004},
  volume =        {\textbf{70}},
  pages =         {066119}
}
```

Comment: Maybe `Sasa, Shin-{I}chi`

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? The reason I ask is that `apsrev4-1` (the default bib style of the `revtex4-1` document class, does *not* produce the ouput you say you're getting.

Comment: Also, do please tell us which TeX distribution you employ and when it was last updated.

Comment: This question needs a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) since we don't know how to get the unwanted output.